# Approximating the modified Bessel’s function with a sum of exponentials

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for an approximation for modified Bessel’s function $I_\alpha(f(t))$ (specially $I_0(f(t))$ or at least $I_0(t)$) with a sum of exponential functions. I mean I want to approximate the modified Bessel’s function by $$\sum_{i=0 \ or \ 1}^{\infty \ or \ m} a_i e^{b_it}$$ which $a_i$ and $b_i$ are real. It would be appreciated if someone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Actually I am going to find a recursive formula to calculate convolution of the modified Bessel function with $H_0(t)$ (as a boundary condition) numerically. With this approach I need to find such approximation to the modified Bessel function. Thanks

Comment: Click the checkmark underneath the upvote count to the left of each solution.  Thank you.

Comment: Over what interval(s) do you want to approximate $I_0(t)$ and with what error?

Comment: Vahid: thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks Antonio. The interval is $\[a,+\infty)$ which $a$ is positive. The error should be less than $10^{-5}$. But it is acceptable with the other errors.

Comment: I think it might be tough to do this with just exponentials since $I_0(t)$ is asymptotic to $e^t/\sqrt{2\pi t}$ as $t \to \infty$.  I'm interested to see.